# How to run code in Pycharm "Python Console"?

Tags: python, pycharm

If I open the Pycharm IDE, go to "tools" and select "Python Console", and copy and paste

```
a=1
b=1
c=1
```

into the console, how do I execute this? If my cursor is at the end of the script (i.e., placed after c=1), I can just hit enter and it works. But the script will not execute if the cursor is placed on one of the first two lines. Hitting Enter only adds a new line between a=1 and b=1. Shift+Enter doesn't work either. Does anyone know how to execute the code without worrying if the cursor is at the very end of the script?

Comment: `shift + alt + E` works for me, but, I get a weird behaviour where an unwanted "recent locations" window appears (see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006986039-How-does-one-use-the-shift-alt-E-command-in-pycharm-). Does that ever happen to anyone? Anyone fixed it?

Answer (score 4):

To run source code from the editor in console:

1. Open file in the editor, and select a fragment of code to be
   executed.

[image]

2. On the context menu of the selection, choose Execute
   selection in console, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:

[origin link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html)

Comment: Be careful! on the **Shift**-Alt-E picture but in reality **Ctrl+Alt+E**

Comment: both work for me. But sometimes I get a weird behaviour where an unwanted "recent locations" window appears (see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006986039-How-does-one-use-the-shift-alt-E-command-in-pycharm-). Does that ever happen to you?

Comment: somehow the window stopped showing up once I did right click and ran the code using the menu...though, not sure if that's a permanent solution...

Comment: Possible, different OS has system hotkeys, which differ in Linux and MacOS. Perhaps, this is such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Alt + Shift + E to execute current line in console

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to execute all lines simultaneously in a similar way?

Comment: Just select lines you want to execute and press Alt + Shift + E